# How does printf statement work here, when printing integer number?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a=034;
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

If I give a value as  034, the output is 28.
if it's 028, it gives an error saying "invalid digit "8" in octal constant".

Comment: The `printf()` behaves badly — there should be a newline at the end of the format string.  The value printed is controlled by the octal notation used; leading zeros mean 'octal' (or base 8), with only digits 0..7.  `034` is 3*8+4 = 28 base 10 (just as 28 = 2 * 10 + 8 = 28); `038` is invalid because `8` is outside the range 0..7.  That's completely tangential to the use of `printf()`.  Note that you could use `%o` to print the result in octal if you wished, and `%X` to print in hexadecimal.

Comment: The error message is a big hint ;-)

Comment: Try a = 34 instead of a = 034

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The value printed is *indirectly* controlled by the octal notation. More directly, the value stored in `a` is affected by the octal notation.

Comment: In C, `int main(void)` is preferred over `int main()`.

Answer (score 14):

In `C` if you start an integer with a zero (`0`) then it is treated as an octal representation of the number. In octal representation there are only 8 valid digits. They are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7.

So you can see that `printf` is working correctly here. `034` is an `octal` number, which is `28` in decimal. So `printf` is printing correct value of int variable `a` which is `34` in octal, which is equivalent to `28` in decimal.

However, the error - while using `038` - is not related to the `printf`. You get error when you try to use a number like `038` because, you are using an octal representation - by starting the number with `0` - but you are using an invalid digit, `8` , which simply does not exist in `octal` number system.

**P.S:** If you start a number with `0x` or `0X` then that is treated as a hexadecimal representation of the number.

**P.S:** If you want to print an integer in octal format, the format specifier is `%o`. For example: `printf("num = %o \n", num);`

**P.S:** If you want to print an integer in hexadecimal format, the format specifiers are `%x` or `%X`. For example: `printf("num1 = %x, num2 = %X \n", num1, num2);`

Answer (score 9):

Integers can be expressed in decimal, octal, or hexadecimal form.

- No leading zeros indicate a decimal number(base10 => 0-9)
- A leading 0 indicates an octal number(base8 => 0-7)
- A leading 0x or 0X indicates a hexadecimal number.(base16 => 0-9,A/a-F/f)

For example, 32 , 040 , and 0x20 are decimal, octal, and hexadecimal representations of the same value.

So if

```
int a=028;
```

gives you :

```
error: invalid digit "8" in octal constant
```

the reason is obvious, '8' is not a valid octal 'digit'.

Comment: I believe lowercase `a-f` can be used as well

Answer (score 6):

`printf()` will do just a normal operation. Integer constants that begin with 0 and not hexadecimal constant are octal constant as the message suggests.

034 = 3 * 8 + 4 = 28

And by the time the printf sees it at execution time,  the number is in binary, looking like this:

```
011100 (binary)
```

That is, sixteen plus eight plus four or 28 (decimal)

Answer (score 2):

It isint the printf function, the concern here is of integer value, to be more precise, integer value of base 8, i.e. Octal numbers.

When we feed an input in integer variable like this :

```
int n = 34;
```

It simply means we are putting in a Decimal number (of base 10) in variable n. But when we put an additional zero in front of digit, like:

```
int n = 034;
```

The compiler interprets it as if we wish to put a value of base 8, Octal number, in variable n. Therefore, instead of putting in the plain Decimal number 34, it treats the input constant as an Octal ((3*8)+4=28) and puts the corresponding binary value for it in n.

On similar notes, we can also feed a hexadecimal value into a plain integer variable, like :

```
int n = 0x34;
```

Here, compiler will simply put the binary equivalent of hexadecimal value 0x34 ((3*16)+4=52) in variable.
*Note. in "0x" , first character is Zero 0, not character 'o' or 'O'*

An example will sum it up :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n;

    //feeding in a Decimal Value
    n = 34;
    printf("\n\nDecimal value with\t%%d : %d", n);

    //feeding in an Octal Value
    n = 034;
    printf("\n\nOctal Value with\t%%o : %o", n);
    printf("\nOctal Value with\t%%d : %d", n);

    //feeding in a Hexa-decimal Value
    n = 0x34;
    printf("\n\nHexadecimal Value with\t%%d : %d", n);
    printf("\nHexadecimal Value with\t%%x : %x", n);

    return 0;       
}

/*
Output:
Decimal value with  %d : 34

Octal Value with    %o : 34
Octal Value with    %d : 28

Hexadecimal Value with  %d : 52
Hexadecimal Value with  %x : 34
*/
```

Hope this explains everything..

Answer (score 2):

Quoted from [N1570, 6.4.4.1 Integer constants](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1): (<- See this link for more information.
)

```
integer-constant:
                ......
                octal-constant integer-suffixopt
                ......
          ......
          octal-constant:
                0
                octal-constant octal-digit
          octal-digit: one of
                0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
```

> If I give a value as 034, the output is 28.

Due to that leading zero, `034` is considered as an "octal-constant" by the compiler, and 34 in octal is 28 in decimal.

> if it's 028, it gives an error saying "invalid digit "8" in octal
>   constant".

Again, the leading zero makes `028` an "octal-constant. However, as you can see above, 8 is not a legal "octal-digit", so the compiler gives you an error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is C language identify numbers written with 0 leading as octal numbers in Integer data type.So if you want to print the zero at the beginning don't use a zero at the beginning of the integer. Try this code. It gives zero at the beginning.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a=34;
    char ds[80];
    sprintf(ds,"%03d",a);
    puts(ds);
    return 0;
}
```

You have to use sprintf which gives formatted outputs.Here ds means Pointer to an char array.Here value of int variable is stored at char array.

Comment: Not numbers in general, just integer constants. `0.125` is a valid number expressed in decimal notation. Also, `0` is a valid integer constant with the obvious value, so it's not true that "You can't use a zero at the beginning of integer" (yes, `0` is an octal constant). In fact, that statement is not true in general. You most certainly *can* use a `0` at the beginning of an integer constant; it just causes it to be interpreted in octal.

Answer (score -3):

```
int a = 34;

printf("0%i\n", a);
```

***Number cannot have zero in front!*** If you need to print a leading zeros like this `034` or `00345` or `007`, you need to print those zeros as characters.

```
printf("00%i", 7);
```

When a number starts with a zero in C/C++/JavaScript and some other languages, it just means some special rarely used type of a number, called Octal.

Comment: `Number cannot have zero in front!` is a bit misguiding. And, are octal numbers rare? Also `rarely used type of a number,` doesn't make much sense here. Did you mean `rarely used base of a number`? Not my downvote  but I believe it might be for the reasons I've mentioned

Comment: This answer is incomplete. It should say "Decimal integer numbers cannot have zero in front…"...