# I am not able to understand the output I am getting for printing an array of 1st eight array elements

Tags: c, printf

I am trying to understand how the following output is generated for the given code. The array of size eight elements stores the numbers as mentioned in the code. Here is the output it generates:

> 0  1  8  9  100  101  110  111

What I fail to understand is why is **8** and **9** a part of the output? Why aren't the values **010** and **011** being printed?

The code is given as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int a[8] = {000,001,010,011,100,101,110,111};

    for(i=0 ; i<8 ; i++)
        printf("%d  ",a[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read up on octal literal constants in any book on C.

Comment: Here's a well answered question dealing with almost the [same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38288452/how-does-printf-statement-work-here-when-printing-integer-number), posted just ten hours ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any integer literal, starting with a `0` is considered an *octal* representation. In your code, you're initializing some of your array members with octal numbers and then printing out the decimal representation (using `%d` format specifier) of them.

So, your expectation and the output differs.

Basically, your initialization, in decimal form, looks like

```
 int a[8] = {0,1,8,9,100,101,110,111}; //first 4 initializers are converted to decimal.
```

On the other hand, just for sake of completion, if you use the `%o` format specifier (octal representation), you can see the first four initializers, as you expected, but the last four also will be printed as octal, like

```
 printf("%o  ",a[i]);
```

will give you an output of

> 0  1  10  11  144  145  156  157

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation! Really helped me a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. You can also [consider accepting an answer that helped you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/244062).

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you start a `int` with `0` it takes it as an octal number(base 8)(0-7).

So, it is printing `0` for `000`

`1` for `001` and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!